# Convert Garmin or iPhone weird GPS Coordinates

Tags: coordinate-system, gps, coordinates, garmin, iphone

I am trying to find a way to convert over 500 locations I have saved in my Garmin iPhone GPS app (iPhone 4S using Garmin StreetPilot v2.7), but I can't find a way to convert these coordinates as they are stored in the mylocations.db file. Any recommendations?

```
name                  latitude    longitude
Starbucks             373512448   1449664512
Wal-Mart Superstore   373473280   1449663232
Subway xin tian di    372450873   1449198830
```

The Subway one should be N31.21847 E121.47044

The Walmart is N31.30417 E121.50937

Comment: What coordinate system is your GPS using? On GPSmap 62s, find out under Main Menu->Setup->Position Format (may be different on your unit). You are expecting decimal degrees, but it's set to something else. You should be able to convert, but you need to know what it was collecting.

Comment: that has no effect at all on the file mylocations.db that contains all this data

Comment: In order to convert your coordinates TO lat/long, you need to figure what coordinate system you are converting FROM.

Comment: exactly, that is why I am here because for the past week I haven't been able to crack it down.

Comment: Is your question, "how to convert coordinates" or "how to determine the original coordinate system", or neither?

Comment: more like how to determine the original coordinate system so that I myself can convert the coordinates

Comment: If you can provide the model of GPS unit we might be able to help you find where to look, but phloem is correct - somewhere in the settings it should tell you what coordinate system and unit format the unit is using, or if it isn't a user selectable setting the unit's specifications should list it. It might be easiest to just load up the locations in Garmin software and save/export a gpx file.

Comment: its an iPhone 4S using Garming StreetPilot v2.7 from http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/garmin-n.-america/id435740864 I already called Garmin Customer Support and they said they dont have a way to export to GPX or any export feature so I had to go in and backup the mylocations.db file myself

Comment: I did some searching around and I can't find anything that specifies how the coordinates are stored internally, either on the iPhone or Garmin's app (not sure which is actually doing the storing). Tried a couple of sources to id those coordinates and the closest I get is China Lambert Conformal Conic, but they'd be well north of where they're supposed to be based on the confirmations you give. Best idea at this point is to go into both the Garmin app settings and the iPhone GPS settings and see if it gives a coordinate system/unit format there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you divide those "strange" latitudes and longitudes by 11930465, you get the North and East degree values you expect:

[image]

But don't ask me why ;-)

Comment: Wow, good find! I reprojected those lat/lons into every coordinate system in the Esri projection engine trying to see what they matched up to and didn't even think they were still WGS-84 with some weird multiplier attached.

Answer (score 6):

@AndreJ's answer is right. I just add the reason for this "strange" number :
it seems Garmin stores its angular coordinates using a 32-bit integer, so that gives 2<sup>32</sup> possible values.
We want to be able to represent values up to 360° (or more exactly -180 to 180), so each degree represents `2^32 / 360 = 11930465`.

So dividing your coordinate by 11930465 will give the decimal value.

By the way, this value encoding is also present in fit files (Flexible and Interoperable Data Transfer) also originating from Garmin.