# Garmin FIT Coordinate System

Tags: coordinate-system, wgs84, utm, garmin

I am trying to decode a `.FIT` file from a Garmin Instinct GPS Watch. Sourced from the file `Lctns.fit`.

However, I am unsure how to interpret the entries values as coordinates.

Given this entry:

```
# Output from parsing the FIT file.

* unknown_1: 571162134
* unknown_2: 92300401
* unknown_254: 12
* unknown_3: 63
* unknown_4: 4930
```

```
# The same entry as Lat / Long

N 47.52.4554
E 007.44.1918
Elevation: 486m
```

How can I determine what coordinate system is being used inside the `FIT` file as to convert to `Latitude` and `Longitude`?

I have tried converting from UTM with no success: http://www.rcn.montana.edu/Resources/Converter.aspx

Comment: there is a tool Java Garmin/ANT FIT file reader https://blog.studioblueplanet.net/?page_id=468

Answer (score 10):

For the latitudes and longitudes, you can divide the numbers by 11930465 (2^32 / 360) to get values in decimal degrees. The values seem to be stored in a signed 32-bit integer range, to represent the full range of geographic coordinate values possible.

Here is a link to a related question: [Convert Garmin or iPhone weird GPS Coordinates](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/122186/convert-garmin-or-iphone-weird-gps-coordinates)

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure how to decode the elevation data from the .FIT file. But once you have the lat/long coordinates in WGS84, you can lookup the elevation for those coordinates with a different service, such as https://www.gpsvisualizer.com/elevation.